# Java casting Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, reflection, casting

I wrote a simple library in which the user extends one of my abstract classes and then passes that class to one of my functions.

```
//user class
class My_robot extends Robot{
}

//My library function
function Robot_maker("path.to.My_robot")
```

The robot maker function then creates an array of the type `Robot[]`. The user then can have the array returned to them by calling another one of my functions `Robot[]` `get_robot_army()`

I know that I can cast the `Robot[]` array element by element but is there a way to cast the entire array at once? (I want to abstract this away from the end user)

Is there a way to use Reflection to change the return type of a function?

///////////////////////////// There is some need for clarity ///////////////////////////

 [The code in question is the function batch_result() on line 124](http://code.google.com/p/imaginarygroup/source/browse/miniBang/trunk/simplePairs/src/com/imaginaryphysics/www/simplepairs/SimplePairs.java?r=59) 
I want to be able to return the class that the user supplied using the function batch_set_relationship() on line 139 

As an example if some one ran  [here on line 88](http://code.google.com/p/imaginarygroup/source/browse/miniBang/trunk/simplePairs/src/com/imaginaryphysics/www/testbed/Simple_test.java?r=59) how can I pass the user an array of the supplied custom supplied class.

Also can some one clarify why the cast to an array of a different type fails.

Comment: This does not appear to be Java.  (`function`?)

Comment: This is your **27th** question on StackOverflow, over the course of **eight months**. With respect, it's well past time that you learned how to properly format code so others don't have to clean it up for you.

Comment: > I know that I can cast the Robot[] array element by element but is there a way to cast the entire array at once?

To what, from what, and why?

Comment: unclear what you're trying to do here. (also, syntax doesn't look very java-ish). So you have a method that returns an array of Robot elements. Where do you need to cast ? Here I would imagine you only want to expose the abstract Robot type (both for creating and retrieving).

Comment: I know I know I do talk in spaghetti. I also can not wright a lick of JS.

Comment: @Mud I am trying to return the Robot[] array; created by Robot_maker() ,as a My_robot[] array. I wont know the class type My_robot needs to be the return type until runtime because that class is being dynamically supplied by the user.Typically I would just return the Robot[] array and cast each element of that array. I want to hide this away from the end user. In general  I am having a hell of a time understanding Java arrays in general for one thing say you have Spoon[] spoons, spoons.length  according to eclipse is a field of the Object class. Not all objects have a length field = /  though.

Comment: I tried to provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can think, add the complete array into an list or any collection and send that as a return type

In that way you can achieve the casting of return type.

With the reflection class you cant change the class type but you can defnitely get the class type dynamically, then later you need to modofy the class type to meet your requirements

Comment: I understand what your saying. I agree. The then later part was what I was trying to come up with crazy ways to hide from the end user.

Answer (score 1):

Responding to the comments above:

> I would just return the Robot[] array and cast each element of that array.

As I said before, cast *to what*? And *why*? The return type of the user's function should be Robot[]. The user sublasses Robot to do what they need to do, and returns Robot[] containing instances of their subclass. Your code doesn't need to know what the subclass is; that's the whole *point* of polymorphism.